# address(this).send(msg.value) returning false but ethers got transfered

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Below is my function:

```
// Function
function deposit() payable external {
    // if(!wallet_address.send(msg.value)){
    //     revert("doposit fail");
    // }
    bool isErr = address(this).send(msg.value);
    console.log(isErr);
    emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value, address(this).balance);
}
```

I use Remix IDE with solidity version 0.8.7 and my question is why send() returns false but the ethers got transferred. Is send() returns false when it success by default?

Comment: It depends on if and how your contract implements the `receive()` or `fallback()` [special functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#special-functions). If it does, can you share them as well?

Comment: @PetrHejda my purpose is to deposit to the contract address that I have created but when I use address(this).send(msg.value) it always returns false but the values got transferred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`address(this).send(msg.value)` effectively just creates an unnecessary internal transaction redirecting the value accepted by "**this contract**" to "**this contract**"

This internal transaction fails because because your contract does not implement the `receive()` nor `fallback()` [special functions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/contracts.html#special-functions) that are needed to accept ETH sent to your contract from `send()`, `transfer()`, `call()` in some cases, and generally any transaction (internal or main) that does not invoke any specific existing function. It does not fail the main transaction, just returns `false` from the `send()` method.

TLDR: The `send()` function is in this case redundant and you can safely remove it. Your contract is able to accept ETH from the `deposit()` function even without it.

Comment: Yes after implementing receive() and fallback() it is working now without the sent() function. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is low level function call, it can fail in after transfer step. If you don't check `success` variable, the compiler is warning you that the call could revert and you might carry on unaware that you ignored failure.
So you should check `success` variable to ensure transaction is success.

```
require(success, "ETH_TRANSFER_FAILED");
```

Comment: yes I have checked it but it returns false by the way values is transferred